# Fermenting Mangrove Jacks M54 at lower temperatures?

Tags: fermentation-temperature

How does [Mangrove Jacks M54 Californian Lager](https://mangrovejacks.com/products/californian-lager-m54-yeast-10g) yeast behave in lower than recommended (18-20°C) temperatures?

The fermentation temperature is around 16-20°C. I've read everywhere that fermenting at higher temperatures leads to off flavours and odours. But is that also true for fermentation at lower temperatures?

My current setup: NC Keg with floating dip tube and pressure release valve (set to 15 psi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a typical lager yeast- you would ferment closer to 10-12c. Typically with lower temperatures off flavors are not the bigger issue- rather it's more about yeast health and pitch rate.

However, from the description of this particular yeast- I'm not sure this is a "traditional" lager yeast. It appears to be for brewing Steam beers (California Common) which are indeed fermented inbetween lager and ale temps. You most likely could ferment it at lower temps with no real issues, but you may need to pitch extra yeast to account for the cooler environment.